# How to build table using MathJax?

Tags: mathjax

I am a beginner. I am trying to build a table using math Jax but it can't compile. how can I add a table?

Comment: MathJax questions are off topic here, since MathJax is not LaTeX, but simply uses a LaTeX like syntax. You might be better off asking on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Probably the wrong place to ask, mathjax has nothing to do with latex, it is just a Javascript application that understands a subset of the latex math syntax. Since tables are normally text it is probably not handled by mathjax, though it might be able to handle array

Comment: Sorry I really don't have any idea where to post this question. Thank you for the suggestion.